# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 Nested Json in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I am trying to fetch the api by using `flutter_bloc` library pattern and i successfully able to get the data but problem is at below i have mention the `json` data the first two elements has an empty `[]` array in `restaurant_branch` and last (third) element has the data in `restaurant_branch` which results a null point exception of ("RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0") in `HomePage.dart` ( in Text widget) code. So how to prevent this issue.

> json data

```
{
    "message": "restaurants returned",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 40,
            "name": "Arnulfo",
            "aboutUs": "Voluptate omnis consequatur saepe doloribus tempore quia error. Praesentium esse blanditiis illo eos qui et deserunt rerum. Velit provident aliquam eveniet qui corporis. Culpa molestiae incidunt eaque unde id tempore. Tenetur ducimus amet hic sunt et.",
            "phoneNumber": 58432,
            "address": "70990 Stark Streets",
            "latitude": "73.6105",
            "longitude": "-95.9985",
            "image": "https://cdn.fakercloud.com/avatars/matthewkay__128.jpg",
            "countryCode": "VE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ",
            "restaurantRegisterDocument": "Est qui voluptatem.",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "createdAt": "2021-09-04T20:24:06.310Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-04T20:24:06.310Z",
            "restaurantTypeId": 1,
            "categoryId": 1,
            "userId": 3,
            "user": {
                "id": 3,
                "firstName": "Marisa",
                "lastName": "Mills",
                "email": "Darrick_Reichert94@gmail.com",
                "phoneNumber": "90428",
                "address": "870 Guadalupe River",
                "gender": "female",
                "language": "ar",
                "createdAt": "2021-09-04T20:14:05.939Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-09-04T20:14:05.939Z"
            },
            "restaurant_branch": []
        },
        {
            "id": 39,
            "name": "Maynard",
            "aboutUs": "Sunt veniam numquam perferendis consequatur. Accusantium mollitia nemo odit nihil alias dolor. Voluptatibus officia consectetur nihil. Voluptas eligendi aliquam.",
            "phoneNumber": 93756,
            "address": "38743 Freda Green",
            "latitude": "-50.3143",
            "longitude": "114.4596",
            "image": "https://cdn.fakercloud.com/avatars/omnizya_128.jpg",
            "countryCode": "PH                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ",
            "restaurantRegisterDocument": "Voluptatem et expedita rerum eos eaque nihil et culpa.",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "createdAt": "2021-09-04T20:24:06.309Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-04T20:24:06.309Z",
            "restaurantTypeId": 1,
            "categoryId": 4,
            "userId": 6,
            "user": {
                "id": 6,
                "firstName": "Layne",
                "lastName": "Turcotte",
                "email": "Jayson_Rice@yahoo.com",
                "phoneNumber": "98802",
                "address": "659 Trudie Keys",
                "gender": "male",
                "language": "ar",
                "createdAt": "2021-09-04T20:14:05.939Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-09-04T20:14:05.939Z"
            },
            "restaurant_branch": []
        },
{
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Kaden",
            "aboutUs": "Et dolore cumque et iusto vel qui iste facere. Quia sed minima. Porro eos inventore qui voluptas animi voluptates fuga commodi magnam. Voluptas eligendi sunt et fugiat repudiandae asperiores maxime sit. Impedit exercitationem laudantium error autem modi voluptas et. Vitae ut non voluptatem culpa eos quae occaecati.",
            "phoneNumber": 94005,
            "address": "920 Sawayn Street",
            "latitude": "-69.1354",
            "longitude": "-176.2695",
            "image": "https://cdn.fakercloud.com/avatars/daniloc_128.jpg",
            "countryCode": "PW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ",
            "restaurantRegisterDocument": "Fugiat ut autem et voluptates aut quisquam distinctio qui aut.",
            "isDeleted": true,
            "createdAt": "2021-09-04T20:14:06.352Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-04T20:14:06.352Z",
            "restaurantTypeId": 6,
            "categoryId": 3,
            "userId": 4,
            "user": {
                "id": 4,
                "firstName": "Santiago",
                "lastName": "Kling",
                "email": "Yoshiko.Block@yahoo.com",
                "phoneNumber": "4436",
                "address": "809 Earlene Square",
                "gender": "female",
                "language": "ar",
                "createdAt": "2021-09-04T20:14:05.939Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-09-04T20:14:05.939Z"
            },
            "restaurant_branch": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Audreanne",
                    "description": "Kreiger",
                    "email": "Waylon.Osinski@yahoo.com",
                    "phoneNumber": 95645,
                    "address": "91601 Clifford Bypass",
                    "country_code": "SM                       ",
                    "image": "https://cdn.fakercloud.com/avatars/nicolasfolliot_128.jpg",
                    "latitude": "-42.0925",
                    "longitude": "-111.4455",
                    "workingHours": "Carolina AI Fresh",
                    "workingDays": "Friday",
                    "offDays": "Thursday",
                    "locationAddress": "802 Hoppe Ranch",
                    "locationCity": "Diamond Bar",
                    "status": 2,
                    "hasParking": true,
                    "instruction": "Bogan",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "isDeleted": false,
                    "createdAt": "2021-09-04T20:14:07.204Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-09-04T20:14:07.204Z",
                    "restaurantId": 10,
                    "cityId": 6,
                    "districtId": 1,
                    "feedbacks": [
                        {
                            "id": 39,
                            "comment": "International Communications Officer",
                            "star": 3,
                            "createdAt": "2021-09-04T20:24:07.433Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2021-09-04T20:24:07.433Z",
                            "customerId": 1,
                            "restaurantBranchId": 4
                        }
                    ]
                },
    ]
}
```

> RecommendedForYouModel

```
class RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranchFeedbacks {
  int? id;
  String? comment;
  int? star;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  int? customerId;
  int? restaurantBranchId;

  RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranchFeedbacks({
    this.id,
    this.comment,
    this.star,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.customerId,
    this.restaurantBranchId,
  });
  RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranchFeedbacks.fromJson(
      Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toInt();
    comment = json["comment"]?.toString();
    star = json["star"]?.toInt();
    createdAt = json["createdAt"]?.toString();
    updatedAt = json["updatedAt"]?.toString();
    customerId = json["customerId"]?.toInt();
    restaurantBranchId = json["restaurantBranchId"]?.toInt();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["comment"] = comment;
    data["star"] = star;
    data["createdAt"] = createdAt;
    data["updatedAt"] = updatedAt;
    data["customerId"] = customerId;
    data["restaurantBranchId"] = restaurantBranchId;
    return data;
  }
}

class RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranch {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? description;
  String? email;
  int? phoneNumber;
  String? address;
  String? countryCode;
  String? image;
  String? latitude;
  String? longitude;
  String? workingHours;
  String? workingDays;
  String? offDays;
  String? locationAddress;
  String? locationCity;
  int? status;
  bool? hasParking;
  String? instruction;
  bool? isActive;
  bool? isDeleted;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  int? restaurantId;
  int? cityId;
  int? districtId;
  List<RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranchFeedbacks?>? feedbacks;

  RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranch({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.description,
    this.email,
    this.phoneNumber,
    this.address,
    this.countryCode,
    this.image,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.workingHours,
    this.workingDays,
    this.offDays,
    this.locationAddress,
    this.locationCity,
    this.status,
    this.hasParking,
    this.instruction,
    this.isActive,
    this.isDeleted,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.restaurantId,
    this.cityId,
    this.districtId,
    this.feedbacks,
  });
  RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranch.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toInt();
    name = json["name"]?.toString();
    description = json["description"]?.toString();
    email = json["email"]?.toString();
    phoneNumber = json["phoneNumber"]?.toInt();
    address = json["address"]?.toString();
    countryCode = json["country_code"]?.toString();
    image = json["image"]?.toString();
    latitude = json["latitude"]?.toString();
    longitude = json["longitude"]?.toString();
    workingHours = json["workingHours"]?.toString();
    workingDays = json["workingDays"]?.toString();
    offDays = json["offDays"]?.toString();
    locationAddress = json["locationAddress"]?.toString();
    locationCity = json["locationCity"]?.toString();
    status = json["status"]?.toInt();
    hasParking = json["hasParking"];
    instruction = json["instruction"]?.toString();
    isActive = json["isActive"];
    isDeleted = json["isDeleted"];
    createdAt = json["createdAt"]?.toString();
    updatedAt = json["updatedAt"]?.toString();
    restaurantId = json["restaurantId"]?.toInt();
    cityId = json["cityId"]?.toInt();
    districtId = json["districtId"]?.toInt();
    if (json["feedbacks"] != null) {
      final v = json["feedbacks"];
      final arr0 = <RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranchFeedbacks>[];
      v.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranchFeedbacks.fromJson(v));
      });
      feedbacks = arr0;
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["name"] = name;
    data["description"] = description;
    data["email"] = email;
    data["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumber;
    data["address"] = address;
    data["country_code"] = countryCode;
    data["image"] = image;
    data["latitude"] = latitude;
    data["longitude"] = longitude;
    data["workingHours"] = workingHours;
    data["workingDays"] = workingDays;
    data["offDays"] = offDays;
    data["locationAddress"] = locationAddress;
    data["locationCity"] = locationCity;
    data["status"] = status;
    data["hasParking"] = hasParking;
    data["instruction"] = instruction;
    data["isActive"] = isActive;
    data["isDeleted"] = isDeleted;
    data["createdAt"] = createdAt;
    data["updatedAt"] = updatedAt;
    data["restaurantId"] = restaurantId;
    data["cityId"] = cityId;
    data["districtId"] = districtId;
    if (feedbacks != null) {
      final v = feedbacks;
      final arr0 = [];
      v!.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(v!.toJson());
      });
      data["feedbacks"] = arr0;
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class RecommendedForYouDataUser {
  int? id;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? email;
  String? phoneNumber;
  String? address;
  String? gender;
  String? language;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  RecommendedForYouDataUser({
    this.id,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.email,
    this.phoneNumber,
    this.address,
    this.gender,
    this.language,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });
  RecommendedForYouDataUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toInt();
    firstName = json["firstName"]?.toString();
    lastName = json["lastName"]?.toString();
    email = json["email"]?.toString();
    phoneNumber = json["phoneNumber"]?.toString();
    address = json["address"]?.toString();
    gender = json["gender"]?.toString();
    language = json["language"]?.toString();
    createdAt = json["createdAt"]?.toString();
    updatedAt = json["updatedAt"]?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["firstName"] = firstName;
    data["lastName"] = lastName;
    data["email"] = email;
    data["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumber;
    data["address"] = address;
    data["gender"] = gender;
    data["language"] = language;
    data["createdAt"] = createdAt;
    data["updatedAt"] = updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}

class RecommendedForYouData {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? aboutUs;
  int? phoneNumber;
  String? address;
  String? latitude;
  String? longitude;
  String? image;
  String? countryCode;
  String? restaurantRegisterDocument;
  bool? isDeleted;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  int? restaurantTypeId;
  int? categoryId;
  int? userId;
  RecommendedForYouDataUser? user;
  List<RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranch?>? restaurantBranch;

  RecommendedForYouData({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.aboutUs,
    this.phoneNumber,
    this.address,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.image,
    this.countryCode,
    this.restaurantRegisterDocument,
    this.isDeleted,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.restaurantTypeId,
    this.categoryId,
    this.userId,
    this.user,
    this.restaurantBranch,
  });
  RecommendedForYouData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toInt();
    name = json["name"]?.toString();
    aboutUs = json["aboutUs"]?.toString();
    phoneNumber = json["phoneNumber"]?.toInt();
    address = json["address"]?.toString();
    latitude = json["latitude"]?.toString();
    longitude = json["longitude"]?.toString();
    image = json["image"]?.toString();
    countryCode = json["countryCode"]?.toString();
    restaurantRegisterDocument = json["restaurantRegisterDocument"]?.toString();
    isDeleted = json["isDeleted"];
    createdAt = json["createdAt"]?.toString();
    updatedAt = json["updatedAt"]?.toString();
    restaurantTypeId = json["restaurantTypeId"]?.toInt();
    categoryId = json["categoryId"]?.toInt();
    userId = json["userId"]?.toInt();
    user = (json["user"] != null)
        ? RecommendedForYouDataUser.fromJson(json["user"])
        : null;
    if (json["restaurant_branch"] != null) {
      final v = json["restaurant_branch"];
      final arr0 = <RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranch>[];
      v.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranch.fromJson(v));
      });
      restaurantBranch = arr0;
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["name"] = name;
    data["aboutUs"] = aboutUs;
    data["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumber;
    data["address"] = address;
    data["latitude"] = latitude;
    data["longitude"] = longitude;
    data["image"] = image;
    data["countryCode"] = countryCode;
    data["restaurantRegisterDocument"] = restaurantRegisterDocument;
    data["isDeleted"] = isDeleted;
    data["createdAt"] = createdAt;
    data["updatedAt"] = updatedAt;
    data["restaurantTypeId"] = restaurantTypeId;
    data["categoryId"] = categoryId;
    data["userId"] = userId;
    if (user != null) {
      data["user"] = user!.toJson();
    }
    if (restaurantBranch != null) {
      final v = restaurantBranch;
      final arr0 = [];
      v!.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(v!.toJson());
      });
      data["restaurant_branch"] = arr0;
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class RecommendedForYou {
  String? message;
  List<RecommendedForYouData?>? data;

  RecommendedForYou({
    this.message,
    this.data,
  });
  RecommendedForYou.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message = json["message"]?.toString();
    if (json["data"] != null) {
      final v = json["data"];
      final arr0 = <RecommendedForYouData>[];
      v.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(RecommendedForYouData.fromJson(v));
      });
      this.data = arr0;
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["message"] = message;
    if (this.data != null) {
      final v = this.data;
      final arr0 = [];
      v!.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(v!.toJson());
      });
      data["data"] = arr0;
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

> HomePage.dart

```
Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: height,
                    child: BlocBuilder<RecommendedBloc, RecommendedState>(
                        builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is LoadingRecommendedState) {
                        return Center(
                            child: PlatformCircularProgressIndicator());
                      } else if (state is LoadedRecommendedForYouState) {
                        return buildRecommendationRestaurant(state.data);
                      } else if (state is ErrorRecommendedState) {
                        return Center(child: Text(state.message));
                      }
                      return Container();
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
  Widget buildRecommendationRestaurant(List<RecommendedForYouData> data) {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
              child: Card(
                  elevation: 0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, right: 5.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.near_me,
                                size: 10.0,
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  '5km',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                  imageUrl: data[index].image!,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                                      child:
                                          PlatformCircularProgressIndicator()),
                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                      Icon(Icons.error),
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.18,
                                  width:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.18,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 10.0, right: 35.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      data[index].name!,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 20.0),
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          '4.5',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 10.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          '(${data[index].restaurantBranch![index]!.feedbacks!.length.toString()} RATING)', //Here on this line getting null because first element is []
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 10.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          ImageIcon(
                                            AssetImage(
                                                'images/food-serving.png'),
                                            size: 15.0,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            'Italian Food - Steake',
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.location_on_outlined,
                                            size: 12.0,
                                            color: TuxedoColor.greyColor,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            'Riyadh',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  CupertinoPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => DetailsPage(
                            id: data[index].id!,
                          )));
            },
          );
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your parent listView's `index` variable for `restaurant_branch` array also. Since `restaurant_branch` is a different array you should use a nested ListView if you want to effectively display branches on the layout. In you case if every `restaurant` do not have multiple branches you can use it like this

```
                              .......
                              Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      '4.5',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 10.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '(${data[index].restaurantBranch![0]!.feedbacks!.length.toString()} RATING)', //Here on this line getting null because first element is []
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 10.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                               ......
```

Comment: How it is possible to have a nested ListView inside this widget `Widget buildRecommendationRestaurant(List<RecommendedForYouData> data)`. Above i have updated the `HomePage.dart` code so that you can understand more clearly

Comment: I'm just saying you should consider creating nested listviews. Currently on your code, If a restaurant has multiple branches, it won't show total feed backs of each branch (Instead it shows the total feed backs of first branch - or some other branch)

Comment: So i have to create a custom widget of `List< RecommendedForYouDataRestaurantBranch >` is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, It all depends on how you design you application

Comment: I also tried with ternary operator initially it was working but when i reach that element containing data then it shows an error 
`data[index].restaurantBranch!.length !=
   0 ? Text(
      '(${data[index].restaurantBranch![index]!.feedbacks!.length.toString()} RATING)',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0,fontWeight:FontWeight.w500),): Text(''),`